# Havel-Hakimi Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I'm a beginner at graph theory, and I recently came across the Havel-Hakimi Theorem which is used to determine whether a sequence of integers is graphical. I am using Chartrand and Zhang's *Introduction to Graph Theory*, but I feel that the proof they provide is lacking. I am wondering whether anyone is aware of a proof for this theorem or where I can find one, preferably an easier one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pearls in Graph Theory: A Comprehensive Introduction* by Hartsfield and Ringel includes a good proof of the theorem. I also believe Google books has the portion of the book about the theorem; It starts around page 10.

Comment: The proof H & R provide is the same one as in my book, but they are much clearer and precise about it. Thank you.