# Proof for Havel-Hakimi Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Havel-Hakimi Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43531/havel-hakimi-theorem)

Hi. I'm a beginner at graph theory, and I recently came across the Havel-Hakimi Theorem which is used to determine whether a sequence of integers is graphical. I am using Chartrand and Zhang's *Introduction to Graph Theory*, but I feel that the proof they provide is lacking. I am wondering whether anyone is aware of a proof for this theorem or where I can find one, preferably an easier one.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi intuit. I think this question is out of scope for cstheory and probably more appropriate for Math.SE. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: I'm sorry, is it possible to move it over to that forum?

Answer (score 1):

The proof in the book "Pearls in Graph Theory" [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=R6pq0fbQG0QC&lpg=PP1&dq=pearls%20of%20graph%20theory&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q=pearls%20of%20graph%20theory&f=false) is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

Look at pages 44 and page 45 of the second edition of Doug West's book Introduction to Graph Theory for what I think is a clear account accompanied by a worked out example.